# HTML5 iPhone App in AppStore

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, html

I have a website based on html5. Is it possible and allowed to implement this website in an iPhone app?

If no: Is there another way to put this site on the Appstore? I haven't found any information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As traisjames says, you could indeed make a wrapper that loads your webpage.

Just porting a website to an app isn't allowed according to Apple's App Store review guidelines ([here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)).

It says so in this line:

> **2.12**
>
> - Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Containing it in a wrapper takes care of this problem since it is not just a website anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Pixate's Freestyle](http://www.pixate.com) isn't a drop in wrapper to turn a webpage into an app, but it might be a good starting place to create your app. It lets you use CSS to define the style of your app.

That's just the look though, you will still need to figure out what you want to do for the app logic.

You will also need to get a [iOS Developer account ($99/year)](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) in order to submit an app to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

If they need to be online to do what the website does you could just make a very basic web browser application and have it always load to your website.  You should also be able to host on the phone too, just like using file:// on your computer.